# how to limit iterations in mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache, mustache.php

I have this mustache template:

```
{{#pages}}
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="page/{{slug}}.html">{{title}}</a></li>
  </ul>
{{/pages}}
```

Now there are more than 50 pages but I want to be able to show only 10 pages. How to do that in mustache eg limiting the iterations to specific number something like:

```
{{#pages:10}} <-- 10 added here as example
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="page/{{slug}}.html">{{title}}</a></li>
  </ul>
{{/pages}}
```

I searched the documentation but could not find the solution.

Thanks for the help

Comment: No logic possible in mustache. You'll have to limit the number of pages before you pass them to the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handlebars is designed as a logic-less templating system. They don't want you to do this in the template.

That said, you should restructure your data (in js/php/whatever) before it gets to the template. e.g...

`var firstPage = pages.slice(0, 10);`